# How Googlebot is finding files that don't have a any link to?

Tags: php, html, googlebot

I'm currently developing a website in PHP and for some parts of the website I use include files. These includes are PHP code so for the browser everything seems to be a long HTML file.

Most of these includes are internal includes in the same top-level directory from the index file. File listing is disabled in the server. It is not possible to see PHP file sources.

But somehow Google bot us hitting one of my internal include files. How can that be possible? From where Google is taking the file names to test? I grep'ed the whole website and there is absolutely no HTML links to any of these internal files.

A practical example could be:

```
//index.php
<?php include 'xpto.php';?>

//xpto.php
<h1>stackoverflow</h1>
```

Google is hitting the file xpto.php.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how are you determining that Google's finding this? Access logs? I'd be looking at accidental dictionary indexes, particularly when accessing the server via IP instead of by domain.

Comment: use a robot txt to prevent bots from finding internal files. There are multiple ways, how this could happen. Was there ever a link to your internal include file (maybe for testing, ...)? have you entered the url in google (instad of address line)? ... if google has index a page it will stay for some time

Comment: @ceejayoz, yes, I'm checking error log and the IP matches google bot. Error log because accessing such file directly was causing an error because it had dependency on the caller file.

Comment: @JarlikStepsto, I believe google may have been cheating. I may have clicked a direct link from inside gmail, that could have made google index the file against my will.

Comment: That'll do it. I'd expect Google to potentially index anything encountered in Gmail, Hangouts, Analytics, etc. Either tell Google not to via a `robots.txt` or (better solution) do what all the modern frameworks do and move includes out of the web root so they're not directly accessible anywhere.